# Como chamar uma function html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um site em *html* em que o objectivo era actualizar uma imagem de meio em meio segundo com uma nova. Igual a uma videovigilancia. Mas precisava de saber como se chama a *function* em *html* para a imagem ir mudando. Pode parecer uma dúvida bem fraca mas sou novo na programação.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title> Cam1 </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script>
        function GetImage(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("img").src = "images/yyy.bmp?t="+Date.now();
            },500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <!-- não sei como fazer aqui-->
    <img id="img" src="images/yyy.bmp" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O teu código está certo. Só falta chamares a função `GetImage`. Podes fazer assim: `<body onload="GetImage()">`. Testa a ver se era isso que procuravas. Uma duvida  esse `?t="+Date.now();` é porquê? o servidor vai dar imagens novas com essa query?

Comment: @Sergio fiz o que disse e acrescentei o onload="GetImage()"> mas em vez de no body, acrencentei na tag img, quanto há sua dúvida, o código foi construido através de vários, e já não estou muito certo a cerca do que ele faz, mas sei que sem ele o função não consegue fazer o get da imagem

Comment: _"mas em vez de no body, acrencentei na tag img"_ - porquê? Na verdade o melhor era usares só o conteúdo da função (só o `setTimeout`) e colocares esse `<script>` no final da página antes de `</body>`. Testa e diz se funcionou.

Comment: @Sergio não está a funcionar, quando uso no body pode simular e teste se conseguir? e não percebi bem a parte de usar só o setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se essa função `GetImage()` só é usada para iniciar o `setTimeout` e se queres que a função seja chamada quando a página carrega, então podes simplificar e fazer assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title> Cam1 </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>  
    <img id="img" src="images/yyy.bmp" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>

    <script>
        // Este script deve estar depois de todo o HTML
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        setTimeout(function(){
            img.src = "images/yyy.bmp?t=" + Date.now();
        }, 500);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando o comentário do Sergio, Deve-se fazer uma pequena alteração em seu `script`.

Dentro do método `setTimeout` chamar a função `GetImage()` novamente pois fazendo isso toda fez que terminar o tempo estabelecido ele chama a função novamente. Ficando assim seu script:

```
<script>
    function GetImage(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("img").src = "images/yyy.bmp?t="+Date.now();
            GetImage();
        },500);
    }
    // Executa a função.
    GetImage();
</script>
```

Comment: Se o `body` demorar a carregar (mais de 500ms) pode acontecer que `#img` ainda não esteja na página e dê erro. Daí que sugeri chamar `GetImage();` no `onload` do body e não no `<script>`. Nesse caso, ou caso o `<script>` esteja no fundo da página, a função nem seria necessária: poderia ter somente `setTimeout` sem função à volta.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo, entendi, é no caso mesmo era só ele chamar mesmo dentro do `setTimeout` porque se não só ira executar um vez.

Comment: Exato, só faz a primeira execução passados 500ms.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza obrigado pela sugestão vou ainda testar e ver se funciona, no entanto arranjei forma de ficar a dar como o Sergio indicou

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda dos comentários do @Sergio, consegui resolver a minha dúvida fazendo o seguinte ao código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title> Cam1 </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script>
        function GetImage(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("img").src = "images/yyy.bmp?t="+Date.now();
            },500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <img id="img" onload="GetImage();" src="images/yyy.bmp" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Bastou acrescentar `onload="GetImage();"` na *Tag* `img` para tudo ficar a funcionar, vou ainda aguarda por uma nova resposta do @Sergio e se resultar posto a outra sugestão dele.